# Unity C# function not working with IEnumerator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a script that when you click a button a movie plays.  I have an IEnumerator to see if the movie is over and when it is close it.  My code worked fine until I added the IEnumerator and now I can't call the playMovie function.

[Image of why I can't call playMovie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/643CR.jpg)

Any ideas on why this might be happening?  This is what the code looks like:

```
public void playMovie(Action callback)
    {
        GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = myMovie as MovieTexture;
    audio = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
        audio.clip = myMovie.audioClip;
        myMovie.Play ();
        audio.Play ();  

        StartCoroutine (FindEnd (callback));
    }


private IEnumerator FindEnd(Action callback)
    {
        while (myMovie.isPlaying) 
        {
            yield return 0;
        }
        callback ();
        yield break;

    }
```

Comment: Does the `StartCoroutine` method actually enumerate the `IEnumerator`?  (i. e. does it use `foreach` on it?)

Comment: "and now I can't call the playMovie function": Why not?  What happens when you try?

Comment: Chris:  I have no idea how to check for that.

Comment: Please show the code for `StartCoroutine`, depending on that you might have a tight loop that's pegging the CPU.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway In Unity3d you need to think of IEnumerables as how we use async/await today (Unity's stuff came first). Think of `StartCoroutine (FindEnd (callback));` as a `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FindEnd(callback), TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()).Unwrap();` and the `yield return 0;` as a `await Task.Yield();`

Comment: @juharr [StartCoroutine is a library function](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html).

Comment: @Amanda When you say "I can't call the playMovie function" please explain more what you mean. Are you getting a compiler error? Does the movie just not start? Please include the code where you call playMovie.

Comment: phoog and Scott, I have updated my question with an image explaining showing why I can't call my function

Comment: Don't pass a callback, rather, make `playMovie` a coroutine and perform whatever operation you want to have happen when it's done after the coroutine from `StartCoroutine` has finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Unity event system doesn't show your method because it takes an Action as an argument. You'll have to make a zero-argument overload for the method.

```
public void playMovie() 
{
    playMovie(()=>{})
}

public void playMovie(Action callback)
{
    GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = myMovie as MovieTexture;
    audio = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
    audio.clip = myMovie.audioClip;
    myMovie.Play ();
    audio.Play ();  

    StartCoroutine (FindEnd (callback));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas on why this might be happening?

There are restrictions when assigning Unity UI event to a function. These are some of the restrictions I remember:

**1**.The callback function should only have one parameter.

**2**.The callback function must be a void function.

**3**.The callback function parameter type must inherit from Object.

Since `Action` is a delegate, it does not meet **#3** requirement and is **not** supported in the Editor.

You can remove **all** the restrictions by performing the Button callback from script instead of the Editor. You can do that by registering to the `Button.onClick` event.

```
public Button playButton;

public void playMovie(Action callback)
{
    GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = myMovie as MovieTexture;
    audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    audio.clip = myMovie.audioClip;
    myMovie.Play();
    audio.Play();

    StartCoroutine(FindEnd(callback));
}


private IEnumerator FindEnd(Action callback)
{
    while (myMovie.isPlaying)
    {
        yield return 0;
    }

    callback();
    yield break;
}

void movieDonePlayingCallBack()
{

}

void OnEnable()
{
    //Register Button Event
    playButton.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonClickCallBack(playButton));

}

private void buttonClickCallBack(Button buttonPressed)
{
    if (buttonPressed == playButton)
    {
        //Your code for when Play Button is clicked
        playMovie(movieDonePlayingCallBack);
    }
}

void OnDisable()
{
    //Un-Register Button Event
    playButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot reference a method with Action parameter from event system in the unity editor.